# Error executing postgres function: the function does not return a "COMPOSITE" type

Tags: postgresql, function, hasura

I have written this postgres function in hasura

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_shipday_filter(p_carriercode TEXT, p_shipdate DATE) 
RETURNS table(shipday text, delivered int, transit int, refused int, undeliverable int, total_exceptions int)
AS 
$$ 
  SELECT view_group_by_shipday_filter.shipday AS shipday, 
         sum(view_group_by_shipday_filter.delivered) AS delivered, 
         sum(view_group_by_shipday_filter.transit) AS transit, 
         sum(view_group_by_shipday_filter.refused) AS refused, 
         sum(view_group_by_shipday_filter.undeliverable) AS undeliverable, 
         sum((view_group_by_shipday_filter.undeliverable + view_group_by_shipday_filter.refused)) AS total_exceptions 
  FROM view_group_by_shipday_filter 
  WHERE (p_carriercode IS NULL OR view_group_by_shipday_filter.carriercode = p_carriercode) 
    AND (p_shipdate IS NULL OR DATE(view_group_by_shipday_filter.shipdate) = p_shipdate) 
  GROUP BY view_group_by_shipday_filter.shipday; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql stable;
```

When I run this in hasura without tracking it executes but when I track this it gives the error

```
Inconsistent object: in function "get_shipday_filter": 
the function "get_shipday_filter" cannot be tracked for the following reasons: 
• the function does not return a "COMPOSITE" type 
• the function does not return a table
```

Context: I've created this view `view_group_by_shipday_filter` from a base table which group by `carriercode`,`shipdate` and `shipday`.I had to add `carriercode`,`shipdate` in group by because I'll be doing filter based on them. I was expecting it will give me unique `shipday` in the view but it's creating duplicate `shipday`.
That's why I'm trying to create a `function` on top of the `view`, to apply filter when necessary and group by only `shipday` so that I get unique `shipday`.

Incase it helps hasura has some constraints for creating postgres function: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/schema/postgres/custom-functions/#pg-supported-sql-functions

I'm still learning postgres function, tbf postgres in general. Stuck here for a while any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I have updated the query without loop still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this after going through hasura's documentation.
It was more of a hasura related problem then postgres.

According to hasura
`If the SETOF table doesn't already exist or your function needs to return a custom type i.e. row set, create and track an empty table with the required schema to support the function before executing the above steps.`

Since I didn't have a SETOF table, I created an empty table

```
CREATE TABLE shipday_filter (
  shipday text,
  delivered int,
  transit int,
  refused int,
  undeliverable int,
  total_exceptions int
);
```

then returned the empty table from the function. Btw I modified the initial function query to suit my need.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_shipday_filter(p_carriercode TEXT, p_shipdate_start DATE, p_shipdate_end DATE) 
RETURNS SETOF shipday_filter
AS 
$$ 
  SELECT shipday, 
         sum(delivered) AS delivered, 
         sum(transit) AS transit, 
         sum(refused) AS refused, 
         sum(undeliverable) AS undeliverable, 
         sum(undeliverable + refused) AS total_exceptions 
  FROM view_group_by_shipday_filter 
  WHERE (p_carriercode IS NULL OR carriercode = p_carriercode) 
    AND (p_shipdate_start IS NULL OR DATE(shipdate) >= p_shipdate_start) 
    AND (p_shipdate_end IS NULL OR DATE(shipdate) <= p_shipdate_end) 
  GROUP BY shipday; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql stable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure each row into fields declared in your return table's type and then just `return next`. Assigning to record in this scenario and then attempting to `return next` that record is too flexible here - I guess because there is no guarantee it has same shape as a row type in your return table (defined inline or as setof).

Alternatively you should consider avoiding the loop and just `RETURN QUERY` using a WHERE if required for any predicate that controls yielding or not yielding a row from the loop. In plpgsql I tend to use loops for side-effects - updating/inserting into other tables.

Another alternative, kind of side-effect too, and a bit verbose, build a temporary table explicitly, insert into each qualifying row into that, and then return that instead.

This example should help:

```sql
DROP function get_shipment_data;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_shipment_data(carriercode TEXT, shipdate DATE)
    RETURNS table(name text, age numeric)
AS
$$
BEGIN
    FOR name, age IN SELECT *
              FROM (VALUES ('row1', 1), ('row2', 2)) data (text, number)
        LOOP
            RETURN NEXT;
        END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


select * from get_shipment_data('aa', now()::DATE)
```